# Is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ever used in Physics?

Tags: vector-spaces

Given that Physics uses vectors extensively, and that the most natural setting for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is a vector space, the question naturally arises: Is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ever used in Physics?

Comment: This should be on the Physics Stack Exchange....

Comment: Yes, of course: to prove that the scalar product induces a norm.

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is implicitely used to define the angle between to vectors. The angle can be used to calculate the scalar product or the cross product which in some cases is more handy.

Comment: Suppose a particle is moving in space, the magnitude of its velocity in x-direction (or in any particular given direction) is always less than its speed. Hope that suits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A major yes! One instance is the proof of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. It is a result of applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in a suitable space. It is used in many other places as well.

Comment: That's the perfect example! See, for instance, Sakurai “Modern Quantum Mechanics”, 1.4 .

Comment: I’m inclined to accept your answer, but I’ve seen others get angry by an answer being accepted very quickly after the question was posted, because they were not given a chance to answer. (There are a lot of unwritten rules here that one needs to learn.) So, be patient, and, with high probability, I will accept your excellent answer after a decent amount of time has passed. In the meantime, I am one of those who have up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a particle is moving in space, the magnitude of its velocity in x-direction (or in any particular given direction) is always less than its speed. Hope that suits

Comment: only drawback is that, one of the vector is always an unit vector, so it doesnt use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in full generality, neverthless it is more physical example than the one given by Ittay.

Comment: I fail to understand what is your motivation for such a question.